# Stalk of Sheaf of Regular Functions is Integral Domain iff X is an irreducible Variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I came across the following problem in my algebraic geometry class and can't figure out how to solve it.

Let $X \subset \mathbb{A}^n$ be an affine variety. Let $\mathscr{O}_{X}$ denote the sheaf of regular functions on $X$ and $\mathscr{O}_{X, a}$ its stalk at the point $a \in X$.

Prove that the local ring $\mathscr{O}_{X, a}$ is an integral domain if and only if $a$ lies in exactly one irreducible component of $X$.

I have proved that $A(X)_{I(a)} \cong \mathscr{O}_{X, a},$ I have tried looking at the codimension of the point $a$, and have considered Nakayama's lemma for one direction, but I am very stuck and would enjoy any tips or hints. I am also quite new to algebraic geometry and don't know anything about schemes, so if you can refrain from utilizing those, I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: What is $X$? Presumably not an irreducible variety. Anyway, look at some concrete examples! For example, the point $(0, )$ in $x y = 0$ in $\mathbb{A}^2$.

Comment: If $X$ is an irreducible variety then every point lies in exactly one irreducible component of $X$: namely, $X$ itself. The question becomes trivial.

Comment: My mistake again, it is just an affine variety. I apologize for that

Comment: OK, now we have a reasonable question. As I said before, go look at some concrete examples first. I don't think it requires much algebraic machinery – there's a clear geometric interpretation to all this.